# Steady flow in fluid dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

***Steady flow*** is the condition in which the flow velocity profile does not vary with time.

Mathematically this is translated to $\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} = 0$, for example in the derivation of Bernoulli's principle for the Navier-Stokes equation.

Why is it not $\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}$?

I know the mathematical differences between the two differente operators, but what is the physical difference?

if the flow profile is constant in time, shouldn't the *total* derivative of the vector field $\mathbf{v}$ be constant everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the flow profile is constant in time, shouldn't the total derivative of the vector field v be constant everywhere?

No. Total derivative $d\mathbf v/dt$ can be written as $\partial \mathbf v/\partial t +  \mathbf v \cdot \nabla \mathbf v$. Value of this derivative at point $\mathbf x$ gives acceleration of a fluid particle when it is at $\mathbf x$. Steadiness does not mean that acceleration of particles that pass through $\mathbf x$ vanishes. Most steady flows have particles accelerating (often they move curvilinearly), so this term is not zero. The steadiness refers to the fact that the velocity attached to the point $\mathbf x$ is constant in time, hence $\partial \mathbf v/ \partial t$ is zero.

Comment: So why does incompressible flow <=> $\frac{d\rho}{dt} = 0$?

Comment: I do not see any relation to incompressible flow.

Answer (score 0):

A Steady flow is one in which the condition (Velocity,pressure and cross-sectional) may differ from point to point but do not change with time.